# Why $Answer will never equal to $Facit

Tags: php, html

The code just displays a simple math question and it then checks if the typed answer is correct or not. And it works flawlessly except that I can't ever make $Answer == $Facit, whatever else I put instead of $Facit works. Ex: 9, ie if ($Answer == 9) {...

it also doesn't seem to have anything to do with local/global scope, because I can echo $Facit inside the if statements.

```
<div id="MainContainer">
<div class="Qt">
    <?php
        $num1 = rand(1,50);
        $num2 = rand(1,50);
        echo $num1;
        echo "+";
        echo $num2;
        $Facit = $num1 + $num2;
    ?>

</div>


<form>
    
<input type="text" name="Answer">
<button type="submit" name="CalcAns" value="submit"> Submit Answer</button>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET["CalcAns"]) != null )
{
    $Answer = $_GET["Answer"];
    
    if( $Answer == (string)$Facit)
    {
        echo "Correct!";
    }
    else if ($Answer == null)
    {
        echo "Type in an answer";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong";
    }
}
?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Every time you load the page, you get a different number, thanks to `rand()`. So whenever you submit the page, even though you entered what `$facit` was when you loaded the page, it is no longer that number.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: According to the correct answer of the @aynber > To reload the page, you must do the `Ctrl + Shift + R` By doing this, you also delete the previous data

Comment: you can create session with $facit value and then can compare session value with answer submitted.....

Comment: Look into [`start_session()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php), it will allow you to store a presistent value across page refreshes.